# What does /dev/ssd do?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

OK,  I am new to linux and I made a mistake that I hope is not catastrophic:

I wanted to type this command:

`sudo dcfldd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd status=on`

But instead I made a typo and wrote this instead:

`sudo dcfldd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ssd status=on`

As I understand it, it erased 17 mb of something, but I'm not sure what.

When I do this command:

`sudo fdisk -l`

There's no mention of `/dev/ssd` either before or after the erasure.

Everything seems to be working well, but I can't find any reference to what `dev/ssd` does on Google, so what did I actually overwrite?

And is it possible revert to the status quo ante?

EDIT: It wasn't 17 mb. I was too hasty again.

This is the output I got after writing the offending command:

```
511232 blocks (15976Mb) written.
511322+0 records in
511321+0 records out
```

Comment: either that, or you created a new file `/dev/sdd` and wrote a bunch of zeros. Why do you think it was 17 mb? Did you get some output? if so, can you post it here?

Comment: `ls -l /dev/ssd` if it is a file remove it. If it is a device do not and investigate further

Comment: Oof. Looks like it just created a regular file so I removed it. at least I rest assured I just didn't destroy something by mistake.